# Message behind modal backdrop

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying a form in bootstrap modal and its backdrop property is static.I'm using "PrimeNG" growl for displaying validation messages but the message is displayed behind the backdrop which does not allow me to close it manually. I have increased its z-index greater than that of the modal but still there is no difference.How can I make message appear over the modal not behind its backdrop.

Comment: Can you post some code? Can you show the code of the message thingy, where you increased the `z-index`?

Comment: Primeng generates a div "div class="ui-growl ui-widget"". I have targeted these classes  for increasing the z-index. I have also increased the z-index in browser.

Comment: And I'm assuming, that these classes do have either `position: absolute` or `position: relative` or anything other than the default position?

Comment: @Patrick .I have made z-index important in my css and it is working now. Thanks for pointing out that Im not applying the z-index properly.

Comment: Did it work now? I was just making sure, because z-index only works for elements that either have `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` positioning, as far as I know

Comment: @Patrick Yeah it is working now. It has absolute positioning.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the div of the dialog it was by default "z-index:1050" in the style why put this code in the css worked for me

```
  .ui-growl {
        z-index: 999999 !important;
    }
```